# Only eager load navigation properties I explicitly specify

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, eager-loading

The skinny:  I am trying to disable eager loading of navigation properties due to circular reference issues when serializing my graph to JSON.

I have these classes:

```
public class Province 
{
    public ICollection<City> Cities { get; set; }
}

public class City 
{
    public Province Province { get; set; }
}
```

When I want to get a collection of cities, I provide this include:

```
set.Include(e => e.City.Province);
```

What ends up happening is that it loads everything up to Province as expected, but it also loads all provinces' cities.  This results in a circular reference during serialization since the same cites returned in my base collection also exist on the provinces.

What I'd expect with explicit loading is that `City.Province` would have a reference, but `City.Province.Cities` would be null.  Instead, `.Cities` is eager loaded with data and I don't want that.

What I ended up trying was preserving references with this:

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling =
    Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
```

That allows my JSON to serialize, but now the clientside has to deal with an array like `[{$id:1, name:"SomeCity"}, {$ref:1}]`.  I thought of finding ways to rebuild the references, but decided it was best to avoid the circular reference altogether.

Comment: Have you tried actually disabling lazy loading on the context?

Comment: @DavidG It didn't occur to me.  I am trying to disable eager loading, not lazy loading.  I know that this lazy loading is not occurring during serialization because the objects are fully populated as soon as they come out of the DbContext.  Still, I'll look into that and see if it does anything

Comment: Explicitly specifying something doesn't then prevent further lazy loading, it just modifies the initial query sent to the database.

Comment: @DavidG As expected, disabling lazy loading with `dbContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false` didn't change anything.  Also, we're not dealing with lazy loading.  It's eager loading that's the problem.  I don't want it to eager load any property for which I have not provide a specific include.

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework is setup so that all references automatically know about each other.  There are a couple of things you can try.

1. Use .AsNoTracking() (right before .ToList()).  It will probably end up loading all the data at all levels, but I think it would remove the circular reference.
2. Create Dtos/Models that store the relationship you want and map to it that way.
3. Before serializing, you have to loop through the children and set the parent references to null directly.  Then it will break the circular data.

Comment: #3 is actually what I ended up doing as a temporary solution to mitigate the circular reference issues.  For #1, I am not looking to simply mask the symptom, but find a solution to the core issue itself.  #2:  Too much extra work.  In the end, I think there has to be a way to tell EF to prevent eager loading of specific navigation fields.  Surely, the engineering team is aware that developers will have classes structured like mine (my province class actually has a Country property and my Country class has a collection of Provinces, so it's even worst when I include all the way to Country)

Comment: A 4th option, depending on how the data is used, is to use an anonymous class at the very top (i.e. the controller).  Instead of returning Json(results) you could do Json(from a in results select new { ... }) to get the exact data you want returned and then you wouldn't need to worry about any circular references.

Comment: Same thing as nulling the properties.  Only masks the symptom and doesn't address the issue.  Besides, when you use the anon object, you'd have to either clone or meticulously select what you need or else you'd just end up copying the references

Comment: The only other option I know about is that you can mark those parent properties with [NotMapped] attribute (or Ignore in fluent api), but that has the consequence of not being able to go up the chain later if you ever needed to.  I believe most people create Dtos to return back with mapping from the entities because you don't normally want to expose your database directly to the outside world.